# Intercept Angular template loading for use with Meteor+Blade

Tags: angularjs, meteor, node-blade

**Little brief:** I'm using AngularJs with Meteor+[Blade](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade) without using [Meteor_angularjs](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs) package for meteor. Blade constructs the body of the page in the server then I manually bootstrap angular in the client.

Blade has template files available under `Template['template_name']` so they can be easily rendered on the client. I would like to do something like:

```
div(ng-include='content.blade')
// HTML => <div ng-include='content.blade'></div>
```

and somehow make it work.
To keep compatibility and not creating new directives I thought it could be possible to intercept the XHR requests angular makes to static templates and add the condition

```
if(URI ends with '.blade') then
    name <- strip '.blade' in URI
    return Template[name]()
```

Which should return the compiled HTML for that template.

**UPDATE:**
Coincidentally I ran into $templateCache and now I think it's the way to go.
I created a 'ngMeteor' module that I'll use for meteor-angular integration.

```
angular.module 'ngMeteor',[], ->
  throw 'Meteor object undefined.' unless Meteor? # Is it fine to put here?

angular.module('ngMeteor.blade',['ngMeteor']).
  run ($templateCache) ->
    $templateCache.put "#{name}.blade", render() for own name, render of Template
```

In my app:

```
angular.element(document).ready ->
  angular.bootstrap document, ['app']

app = angular.module 'app', ['ngMeteor.blade'], ->
app.controller 'mainCtrl', ($scope,$templateCache) ->
  $scope.content = $templateCache.get "content.blade" # Works!!
```

Blade(body.blade):

```
#main(ng-controller='mainCtrl') {{ content }}
```

Now it works, I can get the rendered template from the controller after injecting $templateCache and geting the template by its name but `ng-include` still won't work.

Comment: Let's see if I can finally have my perfect Angular+Meteor+CoffeeScript+Blade+Stylus combo working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous update in the question was actually the correct answer, ngInclude didn't work for me because of `div(ng-include="'content.blade'")` ... yes, the inner quotes! its like the Nth time I have that problem.
In resume the answer is:

```
angular.module('blade').
  run ($templateCache) ->
    $templateCache.put "#{name}.blade", render() for own name, render of Template
```

Template is the meteor global variable where blade will store templates ready to be rendered, then with $templateCache I put the rendered templates with the corresponding names/ids, that way Angular can use them.
**EDIT**: Based on this question I created a meteor package [ng-meteor](https://github.com/olanod/ng-meteor) for braceless angular development in meteor.